# Which merge tool should I use with Mercurial in Windows?

Tags: windows, mercurial, merge

I'm just starting with Mercurial and one of the things that I should do is select a merge tool. I was thinking to use WinMerge for that purpose, but I can't find the way to select this in particular. There are references for all the other merge tools around, but not for WinMerge.

So, should I use WinMerge or there's a better tool for that job (remember, I'm using Windows).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at kdiff3:  http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

It was originally designed for KDE/linux but has been ported to Windows.  It will diff/merge up to 3 files remarkably intelligently, it does a great job of highlighting differences and suggesting how to merge the files, and it's about as intuitive as one could hope.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for KDiff, it is hands-down the best in my experience. When TortoiseSVN has problems merging (resulting in conflicts), KDiff does the job and usually automatically resolves things without needing additional help.

Comment: KDiff3 is open source and is also available on all major platforms.  I use it as my merge tool on OSX and am very happy with it.

Comment: I disagree. I just experienced a scenario where kdiff "auto-merged" a file and did it incorrectly. Only until I installed BeyondCompare did I get a proper merge.

Comment: Yes, I predicted that 4 years ago. :-)

Comment: I am seriously SICK of KDIFF3's limitations. At least it's open source, and I could hack on it a bit. But I wish that there was something better.

Answer (score 6):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com) is the gold standard for compare/merge tools.  I've used it as well as many of the free ones mentioned and can tell you it's worth the $50.

They have a page [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs.php) that discusses configuration for a variety of SCM packages.

Comment: FWIW, Jeff Atwood said he loved BC back before BC3 came out.  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000153.html

Comment: @polara You need the Pro version of BC: http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=moreinfo_merge

Answer (score 5):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/Wiki/Mercurial) works great...

**Edit:** This might be useful:

- [Mercurial MergeProgram](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeProgram)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) which is available for free.

Take a look at the [screenshots](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/screenshots.html) to get an idea of how it works, I found the interface pretty intuitive.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

i use p4merge.
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html

it's beatiful and very clear.

[here](http://markmail.org/message/hyodqao763gzbypq) shows how can you configure.